# Developing an application for performing networking?

Tags: c#, python, c++, networking

I want to develop an application that will be mainly performing networking along with some GUI.
The closest similar application which comes to my mind is `Microsoft Lync`.
I would like to get some suggestions in choosing the right tools as I am the only developer for this project and will be developing in free time.
Being a `C++` guy, having a short stint with `Perl` I felt `C++` requires a lot of lead time but it has the best efficiency.
But in my case efficiency(performance) is not so significant.
Google suggests I should go for `Python`, but then its not always right.
So kindly requesting suggestions from the gurus.

**EDIT:** Making my question more quantifiable -

Which is the best language/tool for developing a networking application with following criteria :-

- Object oriented, compilable to executable unlike scripts and support
  for multi-threading is plus.
- Should NOT have automatic memory management.
- Should be efficient and not hog resources. Java wastes a lot of time
  and resources by compiling at run time :P
- Debugging, profiling, ability on a nice IDE.
- Should be easy to learn or atleast have good learning/community
  support.
- Should require less lead time in developing the source code.
- Should be easy to port to other platforms.
- Should be able to create closed source commercial application without
  paying any royalty.
- And should NOT have more than 1 way of doing things like Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rapid development in your free time, you should definitely go with [Python](https://www.python.org/) and [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).

> Twisted projects variously support TCP, UDP, SSL/TLS, IP Multicast,
>   Unix domain sockets, a large number of protocols (including HTTP,
>   XMPP, NNTP, IMAP, SSH, IRC, FTP, and others), and much more. Twisted
>   is based on the event-driven programming paradigm, which means that
>   users of Twisted write short callbacks which are called by the
>   framework.
>   [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_%28software%29)

Also:

> Twisted includes powerful, high-level components such as web servers,
>   user authentication systems, mail servers and clients, instant
>   messaging, SSH clients and servers, a DNS server and client, and so
>   on, as well as the lower-level infrastructure on which all these
>   high-level components are built. Each component is highly scalable and
>   easily customizable, and all are integrated to interoperate smoothly.
>   It's a tribute to the power of Python and to the ingenuity of
>   Twisted's developers that so much can be accomplished within two
>   megabytes' worth of download.
>   [Source](http://books.google.hr/books?id=JnR9hQA3SncC&pg=PA540&dq=twisted+python+nutshell&hl=en&ei=ZRYJTIKMDo-INMCGtbUE&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Python is a great tool for rapid development, and Twisted is a very fast and mature networking framework. Together they make the best option  for you, even if you don't have Python experience.

The documentation is good and the community is huge around both Python and Twisted. Check [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/index.html) and [Twisted Web](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/) documentation for a better insight.

[Here](http://krondo.com/?page_id=1327) you can find one of the best Twisted introductions out there, that will get you started in the most optimal way. You will understand the basics of inner work in Twisted, and the reasoning behind certain implementation. After that you will learn how to write great Twisted applications.

Comment: Is there something special in Twisted that Python cannot do? Or is it a standard practise in Python to use external libraries. Because in C++ you rarely use external libraries.

Comment: You can do manually in Python everything that Twisted does. In fact, Twisted is written in Python. But to stop you from reinventing the wheel, I assure you Twisted does everything in the best and fastest way. If your goal is to finish your application in a reasonable amount of time, this is the way to go. If your goal is to learn as much as possible about network programming, use pure Python.

Comment: Check the update on my answer for the link on the tutorial i highly recommend. You will understand everything you need from it.

Comment: Yes I have no knowledge at all about networking. So finding a bit difficult in choosing the right tool. So I guess I will go with pure Python then. My understanding of Python is that it is a scripting language. So that means sharing the script with the users and also it requires run time compilation like Java :P. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Looks like a grear tutorial for Twisted. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Yes, Python is a scripting language. It is interpreted rather than compiled.
If you want to learn about network programming, you *can* use pure Python. But I wouldn't say you will not learn about it if using Twisted, specially with the tutorial i posted at the end of my Answer.

Comment: Of course, don't take my word for it, you should wait for other responses and hear out other people before making your own educated decision.

Comment: "Because in C++ you rarely use external libraries" :D